# Telegram Telethon : How to get messages if you know channel hash

Tags: python, chat, typeerror, telegram, telethon

When I have to deal with that kind of link : https://t.me/channelName
I usually get message from channel like this :

```
async def main():
    channel = await client.get_entity('channelName') 
    messages = await client.get_messages(channel, limit = N ) 

#...Code etc..

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

How do you get message if you link is like this ?
https://t.me/joinchat/DDDDDxxxxAAAA

I know that 'DDDDDxxxxAAAA' is the channel_hash, so I joined the channel by telegram client and I tried get channel id and message object :

```
channel_hash = "DDDDDxxxxAAAA"
channel = await client(functions.messages.CheckChatInviteRequest(hash=channel_hash))
```

Now , channel object containes channel ID and many others fields.
example : (chat=Channel(id=123456789,...etcc
So , I tried like this:

```
messages = await client.get_messages(channel, limit = N )
```

but it returns :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\telethon\sessions\memory.py", line 192, in get_input_entity
    return utils.get_input_peer(key)
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\telethon\utils.py", line 235, in get_input_peer
    _raise_cast_fail(entity, 'InputPeer')
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\telethon\utils.py", line 138, in _raise_cast_fail
    raise TypeError('Cannot cast {} to any kind of {}.'.format(
TypeError: Cannot cast ChatInviteAlready to any kind of InputPeer.
```

```
TypeError: Cannot cast ChatInviteAlready to any kind of InputPeer.
```

How to get messages if you only know channel hash ?
Thanks for help

Comment: `channel` in this case is an instance of `ChatInviteAlready` which can't be used as an entity. `ChatInviteAlready` has a `chat` property which should contain an `id`. Use that to do your `get_messages` request.

Comment: Thanks Watzon, it works.  ```messages = await client.get_messages(channel.chat, limit = N )``` Solved